# function won't execute the query inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

i have a function that won't execute the cffunction inside of it. Everytime i check network in developer tool the script isn't executed.

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="path/exemple" jsclassname="jsobj_path_page" />
```

```
function Edit_LONG(){

    var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
    var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude').value;


    $('##editModal').modal('hide');
    var cfcAsAjax = new jsobj_path_page();
    cfcAsAjax.queryUPDATE_longitude_latitude(longitude,latitude);

}
```

Comment: Are there any errors on console/network?

Comment: this is the problem in console it show nothing and network there is  0 action

Comment: i found the solution i should add the path <cfajaxproxy cfc="path/exemple" jsclassname="jsobj_path_page" /> to the modal file not only in the function file
thank you sir, your comment give me another idea to try you helped me alot

Comment: That being the case, you should either answer the question or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: i should add the path that call the query cfc function to the modal file too not only in the js function file only. `<cfajaxproxy cfc="path/exemple" jsclassname="jsobj_path_page" />`